# How to use Python SMB connection when you don't know the server's IP?

Tags: python, smb, pysmb

I'm using PySMB right now:

https://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/smb_SMBConnection.html

and the SMBConnection.connect spec is problematic because it requires knowing the server's IP address.

What about a usage case where I don't know the IP address and looking up the IP address fails? I already went through the steps in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10956/finding-the-remote-ip-address-used-by-a-mounted-smb-share although the server in question isn't a Bonjour service.

I tested using the smb address (that would normally be typed into the Finder's "Connect To Server" option in Mac OS) in the connect function and that didn't work.

Is there an alternative library that takes an SMB address (instead of IP address), or at least a canonical/proper way to translate that into an IP address for this? Either way, please post an example.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar kind of issue, did u try making the following changes?

```py
smb = SMBConnection(user_id, password, client, server_name, domain = domain, use_ntlm_v2=True, is_direct_tcp=True)
ip = socket.gethostbyname(server_name)
print(ip)
smb.connect(server_name, 445)
```